# Flyway migration not working repair required

Tags: flyway

I'm using flyway for migrations. Flyway version is Flyway 3.2.1 by Boxfuse. When I am executing

```
./flyway migrate -url=jdbc:postgresql://$FLYWAY_DATABASE_HOST/$FLYWAY_DATABASE_NAME -password=$FLYWAY_DATABASE_PASSWORD -user=$FLYWAY_DATABASE_USER
```

I'm getting following error

```
"ERROR: Validate failed. Migration Checksum mismatch for migration 80
 Applied to database : -401430104
 Resolved locally    : -485639995
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I'm not able to get(or which command) to execute to do repair

Comment: The tag I added because I thought I'm using sbt as a build tool

Answer (score 8):

`Migration Checksum mismatch` means that the contents of a particular migration file has changed since you executed it, and that means that your script collection might not be a faithful representation of the database schema.

If you are happy that the scripts are still good (eg the changes were comments and formatting) then `flyway repair` with the same URL and credentials will clear this error. If not, then you should either revert the changes, or `flyway repair` and accept the mismatch.